# Identify which [SelectField] [DropDownMenu] fired onChange

Tags: material-ui

I am programmatically rendering multiple SelectField and DropDownMenu components. I am trying to work with a single onChange handler functions, but I'm have not found a way to reference specific SelectField / DropDownMenu that triggered the event so I can update state accordingly.
The params passed for the onChange event seem not to contain any helpful information to identify the firing components. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example of how this can be done

https://jsfiddle.net/davidebarros/k9ng7bk9/

This is assuming you are familiar with the es6 arrow function syntax.

```
state = {
  dropDown1: 1,
  dropDown2: 4,
  selectfield1: null,
  selectfield2: null
}

onChange = (type) => (event, index, value) => {
    this.setState({
    [type]: value
}) 


//In your render method 
<SelectField
      floatingLabelText="Select Field 1"
      value={this.state.selectfield1}
      onChange={this.onChange("selectfield1")}>
      <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Select 1, value 1" />
      <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Select 1, value 2" />
</SelectField>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the value from the `event` object? Thing is I am using enzyme to simulate a change event during tests and I can only pass an event object to it: `selectField.simulate('change', {
      target: { value: 'newValue' },
    });`

Comment: or you can try changing  `onChange` function to be `this.setState({ [type]: value || event.target.value })`

Comment: Hum this isn't great but could be a temporary solution. Seems to just be the way `MaterialUI` works and there is no way to get it from the event object. `Enzyme` also doesnt seem to support simulating an `onChange` with more parameters `(event, index, value)` in this case. Cheers!